# How to handle "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection, timeout, mysql-connector

I am using VB.NET and MySQL, I am testing my application whether it can handle wrong database connection.

one particular case is when I input wrong database IP address, for example instead of `192.168.1.100` I'll input `192.168.1.101` which is wrong.

For this reason I tried to use `try, catch` my try catch is able to catch that kind of error but unfortunately my computer hangs out for certain minutes.

This is the code I am using

```
Public Sub Update_DB_Con()
    Check_DB_Con()
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            frmStatus.Database_Status = "Connected"
            MysqlConn.Close()
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            frmStatus.Database_Status = "Disconnected"
            Console.WriteLine(myerror)
            Console.Write("IAM CATCH")
        End Try        
End Sub
```

So my question is, how do I handle properly the timeout request of MySQL?

Comment: You can shorten the Connection Timeout with an attribute on the connection string, and probably also with a property on the Connection object, but I really only use SqlConnection myself.

Comment: show your connection string(_hide server name and db name_)

Comment: Do you have specified port(`ex.Port:3306;`) in mysql connection string?

Answer (score 1):

You are up against the design of TCP/IP in trying to solve this problem. The host you actually specified has no server running on the MySQL port (usually 3306) and so doesn't respond to the connection request from your program. It neither accepts nor rejects the connection. Because of the global reach of TCP it wants to give sufficient time for a server to respond to a Connect. That's why it doesn't time out in a few milliseconds.

Connector/NET has built in support for a pool of servers so it tries again automatically after a timeout.

Try adding ConnectionTimeout=5 to your connection string. The default is 15.  But be careful about doing this in production; the defaults were chosen after long experience with large busy systems for resiliency.